# How to make slide and fade effect before than addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a slide and fade effect based on jQuery. Everything works fine before adding the function `addClass`. But after adding this class, the slide and fade effect disappear.

When I add `addClass('hide')` after `FadeSlideToggle.call(box)`, the javascript effect disappears.

Could someone help me on that? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            background: red;
            width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Some Content Here</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>  
    <p><button>FadeSlideToggle</button></p>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var box = $('div.box');

            function FadeSlideToggle(){

                return $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    'height': 'toggle'  
                }, 2000);
            };

            $('button').on('click', function(){
                FadeSlideToggle.call(box);
            });

    </script>
</body> 
</html><html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            background: red;
            width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Some Content Here</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>  
    <p><button>FadeSlideToggle</button></p>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var box = $('div.box');

            function FadeSlideToggle(){

                return $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 'toggle',
                    'height': 'toggle'  
                }, 2000);
            };

            $('button').on('click', function(){
                FadeSlideToggle.call(box);
            });

    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `addClass` takes effect immediately, it's not queued like animation methods.

Comment: @Barmar How can I make slide and fade effect first and then addClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use complete callback

```
var box = $('div.box');

function FadeSlideToggle(callback){

    return $(this).animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        'height': 'toggle'  
    }, 2000, callback);
};

$('button').on('click', function(){
    FadeSlideToggle.call(box, function() {
         //do something you want
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for LowerClassOverflowian

One of the solution is to use jQuery UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var box = $('div.box');

            function FadeSlideToggle(speed){

                return $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '0',
                    'height': 0 
                }, speed || 2000);
            };

            $('button').on('click', function(){
                FadeSlideToggle.call(box, 5000).addClass('hide', {
                    queue: true
                });
            });

    </script>
```